# Trying to create permalinks for comments using laravelista/comments package

Tags: php, laravel, comments, laravel-5.8, permalinks

I want to create permalinks for comments so users on my site can link to a comment thread (aka including parent and child comments)

A good visual example is the layout and link format of this -

https://www.deviantart.com/comments/1/625945421/4194305308

The comments package creates a database table with unique comment IDs and model locations, so I believe it could be used to create permalinks.

I was considering using this package but am unsure how to get it to work with the above comments package.

https://github.com/IsraelOrtuno/permalink

Any solution is welcome along with any comments telling me how naive I am for not seeing the obvious haha.

Comment: There is no special circumstance here. You just need to create a route/controller/view for comment ids/slugs and render it and all its parents and children.

Comment: @KurtFriars will i need to use the permalink package or just use a migration to add slugs to the comments table? Also, how should I define the route/view to automatically generate for each comment?